# UUID primary key in sequelize gives: (node:6927) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value)

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, uuid

I know this is a well reported issue yet it's not well documented and the workarounds are not so "**professional**" like "**Removing strict mode from MySQL**"

I want to set a `uuidv4` as a primary key using sequelize in my app but I'm getting  `(node:6927) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: Field 'id' doesn't  have a default value)`

Setting it in the migration is giving me this error, yet if i add it in my controller it seems to work.
my question is, is my workaround a proper solution or there's a better way to do i?

My migration

```
'use strict';
const {Model, DataTypes} = require('sequelize');
const uuidv4 = require('uuid').v4;
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, DataTypes) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Etudiant', {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: uuidv4(),  // why does this not work ?
        unique: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      nom: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      prenom: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      mail: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      convention: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        allowNull: false
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, DataTypes) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Etudiants');
  }
```

my route:

```
const express = require('express');
const models = require('./src/database/models');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('./src/database/db');
const uuidv4 = require('uuid').v4;


const app = express();


app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    return models.Etudiant.create({
        //id : uuidv4(),    // this is where I think is not a propersolution
        nom: "AL HR",
        prenom: "Malek",
        mail: "mail@gmail.com",
        convention: "4rzd-3be2lk-4glma"
    });
});


app.listen(3000, console.log('G'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the solution was pretty simple:
if I understand correctly:
The migration defines the datatypes and it doesn't set default values for the fields.

When I added the **defaultValue** to my model thogh it Worked, So:

Solution:
Add the `id` field to your Model like so:

```
 id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
/* the rest of your columns ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

The `defaultValue` is a table property that is related to defualt value at database level. At your code, this is being determined as a value (returned by uuid() function) and should not work indeed.

To fix that, you may need to use some uuid extension in database to generate this uuid, using `Sequelize.fn`.

```js
id:   {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('UUID()'), // this UUID() is a mysql function, not a node_module.
        unique: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
```

Comment: didn't work, I tried first by modyfing the existing migration, and then i undid all migrations modified the migration and migrated again, what ever I put it generates Error in SQL syntax tried the "generate_random_uuid" too using Sequelize.fn and .literal. any other thoughs?

Comment: maybe you need to check first if the `UUID() ` is available by default. Or even check if this is the function to be called in mysql. `generate_random_uuid` works for me but on postgres.